# How to write try-catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have java method which encrypts a string:

```
public String getCurrency(String hash){
                try {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                     md.update(hash.getBytes());

                     byte byteData[] = md.digest();

                     /** convert the byte to hex format */
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                         for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
                     sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                     }              
                    return sb.toString();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              return sb.toString();                
            }
```

I use Netheans IDE. The problem is that when I try to compile an error appears that I must create a `try-catch` statement for this part `("SHA-256")`.

When I create it using Netbeans this code appears:

```
public String getCurrency(String hash){
                try {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                     md.update(hash.getBytes());

                     byte byteData[] = md.digest();

                     /** convert the byte to hex format */
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                         for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
                     sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                     }              
                    return sb.toString();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              return sb.toString();                
            }
```

Now when I again try to compile the code this error message appears:

> "varible sb is not declared"

How I can return properly the encrypted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring your `StringBuilder` *inside* the `try` block. This means its scope is limited to that block.

Declare it prior to the `try`

```
public String getCurrency(String hash) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(hash.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        /** convert the byte to hex format */
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }              

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others already stated, the problem is that your `sb` variable is defined in the `try` block, hence only accessible there. Moving the declaration outside the `try` block will make your code compile, but I doubt it is the desired behavior.

What will happen if an exception occur when you call `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")`: the `NoSuchAlgorithmException` is catched by your catch, the stack trace is printed to the `System.err` and your method happily returns the `toString()` of an empty `StringBuilder`, which is the empty `String`. Your code which called that method is not aware of the raised exception, and can not handle the exception.

Alternatives (although what is best completely depends on your application):

- let [the method throw the exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) and do proper error handling outside that method
- catch the exception in that method as you did now, but return `null` instead of the empty `String`, which allows the caller of this method to recognize something went wrong.

A nice starting point on `Exceptions` is the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your variable `sb` outside of the try/catch block.